# unable to see vue component on logged in profile

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a vue component which can be seen on other users's profile but not on logged in user.

when I visit other user's id i can see that component but when I come back to my id it disappears

profile url is `/myplace/{username}`

vue component :

```
   <template>
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-colored/700/09_bell-3-512.png" style="height:50px;margin-top: 30px; margin-left:0px!important;">
    </template>
   <script>
import $ from 'jquery'
import axios from 'axios'
import Notification from './Notification.vue'

export default {
  components: { Notification },
  props:['username'],
  data: () => ({
    total: 0,
    notifications: []
  }),

  mounted () {
    this.fetch()

    if (window.Echo) {
      this.listen()
    }

    this.initDropdown()
  },

  computed: {
    hasUnread () {
      return this.total > 0
    }
  },

  methods: {
    /**
     * Fetch notifications.
     *
     * @param {Number} limit
       */
        fetch (limit = 5) {
         axios.get('/notifications', { params: { limit }})
         .then(({ data: { total, notifications }}) => {
          this.total = total
          this.notifications = notifications.map(({ id, data, created }) => {
            return {
              id: id,
              title: data.title,
              body: data.body,
              created: created,
              action_url: data.action_url
            }
          })
        })
       },
```

in blade view:

```
<notifications-dropdown :username="{{json_encode($user)}}">
</notifications-dropdown></a>
```

app.js:

```
import './bootstrap'
import Vue from 'vue'

import NotificationsDemo from './components/NotificationsDemo.vue'
import NotificationsDropdown from './components/NotificationsDropdown.vue'


new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  components: {
    NotificationsDemo,
    NotificationsDropdown
  }
})
```

Comment: I think problem is that because you binded username prop.Consider about removing the `:` from username.

Comment: @BelminBedak doesnt worked :(

Comment: Sorry but code you posted doesn't give some useful infos to us.This is thing that I noticed as wrong from provided code.Consider about providing more code.

Comment: @BelminBedak updated my code

Comment: Thanks, are you getting any error in console when your component crashes ?

Comment: @BelminBedak getting this wierd error:  `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
    at Array.updateDOMProps (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/js/app.js:91:1), <anonymous>:4875:19)
    at invokeCreateHooks (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/js/app.js:91:1), <anonymous>:4187:22)
    at createElm (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/js/app.js:91:1), <anonymous>:4098:11)
    at createChildren `